# How to get/set user profile picture in twilio chat api for ios (xamarin)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, twilio, twilio-api

I want to get user's profile picture from twilio chat in my app. I am aware of how to get the token and user-identity, but I want to show user profile picture for both sender and receiver in channel. So is there a way to get user's profile picture or its url?

Comment: Not using Twilio , how about url property in doc contain the profile ?https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/users

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I have checked that but not getting result from it as i want.